# OPL Tuple Formulation: Constraint (sum over "one element " of tuple) equals

Tags: arrays, tuples, opl

After using OPL primarily for formulating MILP in the form of arrays, I am trying to convert some problems into tuple formulation to benefit from sparse data!

As I am not from a programming background, it took me some time to understand the data structures and how they are working. I think I now understand the basics but got stuck trying to formulate my constraints. I read through examples, watched YouTube tutorials, and just tried different codes, but I did not come up with a solution yet.

The problem: The problem itself is part of a multiperiod-(reverse supply chain)-location-allocation problem.

The constraint I am currently trying to formulate:

> All products (p in P) with size (s in S) supplied in an area (a in A) need to be picked up and transported to a location (l in L) in each period (t n T)

Because the same problem exists for other constraints, I would be very thankful for an answer that shows me where my error (in thinking) is.

---

Part of my  array formulation (works fine):

```
int supply[A][P][S][T] =...; (data is read from on excel file)
dvar int+ transport[A][L][P][S][T] in 0...100;
```

I skip the formulation of the goal function (minimization: sum over all periods, products, sizes, areas, and location transport*cost)

The (first) constraint:

```
forall (p in P, s in S, a in A, t in T)
supply [a,p,s,t]==sum (l in L) transport[a,l,p,s,t];
```

My tuple formulation (declaration):

```
tuple Treturns{
  int A;
  int P;
  int S; 
  int T; 
 
}

{Treturns} returnsT=...; (read from excel, could also be generated in mod file)


//Return including supply Value
tuple Tsupply{
 Treturns ret;
 int supplyvalue;
 }

{Tsupply} supplyT with ret in returnsT =...; (read frrom excel)

//Transport --> use tuple in dvar fomulation
tuple Ttransport{
  Treturns ret; //area, product, size and period
  int L; //location
}

{int} L=...; (data file connection) 
 
{Ttransport} transT with ret in returnsT, L in L ={<c,l> |c in returnsT, l in L}; 



dvar int+ transport[transT] in 0..100;

minimize sum(c in transT)transport[c]
```

And here is a try for the constraint:

```
subject to {
  forall (d in supplyT:d.supplyvalue>0, c in transT:c.ret==d.ret)
       d.supplyvalue ==sum (l in L)transport[c];
    
}
```

The model cannot be solved with this constraint. If I change the "==" to "<=" the model is solved, and I can see that the constraint does not do what I want. ;)

In the current formulation (with <= instead of =), I get different values for each period, product, size, and area. But the value is always the same for both locations.
Thus, if, for instance, 3 units of product p, size s are returned in period 1 and area 1 --> transport[c] gives "2" as a result for each location (l) (and the combination of p,s, a, and t).

If the constraint would be working correctly, it must be three transported units in total and not four (and the values have to be different for the two locations (0/3, 1/2, 2/1, 3/0)).